# Cannot change focus/state for button png using selector element

Tags: android, android-studio

```
Android Studio 0.3.7
```

Hello,

I have created 2 buttons png and patched using draw9patch.
The buttons will indicate whether the buttons is pressed or unpressed.

I have the following `buttons_colours.xml` in my values directory

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_focused="false"
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rd_btn_press"/> <!-- pressed -->

    <item android:state_focused="true"
       android:state_pressed="false"
       android:drawable="@drawable/rd_btn"/>        <!-- unpressed -->

    <!-- Default -->
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rd_btn"/>

</selector>
```

In my layout for the button I have this:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Start"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/rd_btn"/>
```

Problem 1: I get an `element selector must be declared` in my buttons_colours.xml

Problem 2: Not sure if this is related to problem 1, but the button never changes to my rd_btn_press state when I press it.

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have set wrong background for the button. Replace `@drawable/rd_btn` with `` `buttons_colours `` :

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Start"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:background="@drawable/buttons_colours"/>
```

also, I don't know why you have two states in your items in the selector. Here an example of working selector:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <item android:drawable="@drawable/rd_btn_press"
          android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rd_btn"
          android:state_focused="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/rd_btn" />
</selector>
```